# UITypeEditor is not closing properly

Tags: c#, winforms, uitypeeditor

I am using a UserControl with a UITypeEditor. The user control has OK and Cancel buttons that do nothing except display a MessageBox with either OK or Cancel and then hide the user control. But when I click one of the buttons, the PropertyGrid displays an empty box where the UserControl was until I click away. Then the box disappears and the dialog is displayed.

[image]

Here is the user control code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace j2associates.Tools.Winforms.Controls.DesignTimeSupport.SupportingClasses
{
    public partial class SimpleTest : UserControl
    {
        public bool Cancelled { get; set; }

        public SimpleTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cancelled = false;
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cancelled = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the UITypeEditor code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

using j2associates.Tools.Winforms.Controls.DesignTimeSupport.SupportingClasses;

namespace j2associates.Tools.Winforms.Controls.DesignTimeSupport.Editors
{
    internal class TimeElementsEditor : UITypeEditor // PropertyEditorBase<TimeElementsUserControl>
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
        }

        public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(j2aTimePicker.TimeElementOptions))
            {
                var editorService = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
                if (editorService != null)
                {
                    using (var st = new SimpleTest())
                    {
                        editorService.DropDownControl(st);
                        if (st.Cancelled)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("OK");
                        }
                        editorService.CloseDropDown();
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not try it but there's a major flaw in this approach.  You cannot afford to jerk the focus away from a dropdown.  The PropertyGrid uses mouse capture to detect when the dropdown needs to be rolled-up again.   Using MessageBox.Show() cancels mouse capture.  Use, say, ErrorProvider or a Label to provide diagnostics or throw an exception when you are unhappy with a value.  Or use UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal

Comment: You should probably not control hiding or closing from within the control itself. Rather do it from the container.

Comment: Hans, The example given was a very simplified set of code to demonstrate the problem. The MessageBox code was in the Editor code, not the UserControl so it was not executed until the UserControl had closed. As such, there is no jerking the focus away from the dropdown.

Comment: leppie, hiding the UserControl is what caused my issue in the first place and should probably never be done. Passing the EditorService to the UserControl so that you can call it's CloseDropdown method when processing is finished is the technique used  in the UITypeEditor walk through code.

Comment: leppie, do you have some sample code for closing it from the container? I agree that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, it's always easy when you find it.

I needed to pass the IWindowsFormsEditorService in via an overloaded constructor, cache it and then call it's CloseDropdown method in the Button Click events instead of hiding the user control. It now works as expected.

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays an OK and Cancel button. When one is pressed, 
/// the dialog is closed and a message box is displayed.
/// The actual value of the property is unchanged throughout.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The ToolboxItem attribute prevents the control from being displayed in the ToolKit.</remarks>
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public partial class SimpleTest : UserControl
{
    public bool Cancelled { get; set; }

    private IWindowsFormsEditorService m_EditorService;

    // Require the use of the desired overloaded constructor.
    private SimpleTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal SimpleTest(IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService)
        : this()
    {
        // Cache the editor service.
        m_EditorService = editorService;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancelled = false;
        m_EditorService.CloseDropDown();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancelled = true;
        m_EditorService.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

And here is the modified editor call:

```
using (var simpleTest = new SimpleTest(editorService))
{
    editorService.DropDownControl(simpleTest);
    MessageBox.Show(simpleTest.Cancelled ? "Cancelled" : "OK");
}
```